# Why does the accordion class trigger other panels with different names

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

why do some of my acordions triger other acordions when they are all named differently.

I have been trying to solve this issue that when I open the second acordion in the second, third or forth panel and the second acordion for the first panel is open they close it. This same issue happens various times with other panels tirggering different panels from what they should be.

```css
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic);
    body {
      background: #111d27;
      color: #111;
      /*min-width: 320px;*/
      min-width: 1024px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1.6;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      position: relative;
      padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    .main {
      text-align: center;
      color: #777;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
      font-family: 'Lato';
    }
    .main img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 32px;
    }
    .main li:first-child,
    .main li:last-child {
      padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    }
    .main li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 13px;
    }
    .main li + li {
      border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    }
    .main big {
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .main h3 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 36px;
    }
    .main h4 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .main span {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #999;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .main li:nth-last-child(2) {
      padding: 5px 13px;
    }
    .main button {
      width: auto;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 9px 24px;
      background: #aaa;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity .2s ease;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
    .main button:hover {
      opacity: .9;
    }
    .main button:active {
      box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    /* main color */
    .a-green big,
    .a-green h3 {
      color: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-green h4 {
      color: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-green button {
      background: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-yel big,
    .a-yel h3 {
      color: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-yel h4 {
      color: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-yel button {
      background: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-red big,
    .a-red h3 {
      color: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-red h4 {
      color: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-red button {
      background: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-blue big,
    .a-blue h3 {
      color: #2e5dea;
    }
    .a-blue h4 {
      color: #2e5dea;
    }
    .a-blue button {
      background: #2e5dea;
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<section class="container">
  <div class="row white">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <ul class="main a-green">
          <li>
            <big>COLLAPSIBLE 1</big>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Acordions</h4>
          </li>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <ul class="main a-yel">
          <li>
            <big>COLLAPSIBLE 2</big>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Acordions</h4>
          </li>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <ul class="main a-blue">
          <li>
            <big>COLLAPSIBLE 3</big>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Acordions</h4>
          </li>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse8">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse9">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <ul class="main a-red">
            <li>
              <big>COLLAPSIBLE 4</big>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4>Acordions</h4>
            </li>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse10">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse11">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse12">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse12" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /block -->
  </div>
    <!-- /row -->
</section>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do see that you're including multiple versions of jQuery, Bootstrap etc. Prune that down to one each.

Comment: diddo, took out the last ones from my folders and left the CDNs

Comment: There are four such lines - <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> - id attributes must be unique.  Change id to 'accordian1', 'accordian2' ...etc... And it would not cause such errors.

Comment: I'd recommed to retest this with just 2 accordions and reduce the code here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` value should be unique, to make the collapsing work, you have to set different ID values for each `panel-group`, and the same with `data-parent` attribute of children links.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
...
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="">
...
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
...
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="">
...
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion4">
...
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="">
```

Here is the full code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic);
    body {
      background: #111d27;
      color: #111;
      /*min-width: 320px;*/
      min-width: 1024px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1.6;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      position: relative;
      padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    .main {
      text-align: center;
      color: #777;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
      font-family: 'Lato';
    }
    .main img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 32px;
    }
    .main li:first-child,
    .main li:last-child {
      padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    }
    .main li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 13px;
    }
    .main li + li {
      border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    }
    .main big {
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .main h3 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 36px;
    }
    .main h4 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .main span {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #999;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .main li:nth-last-child(2) {
      padding: 5px 13px;
    }
    .main button {
      width: auto;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 9px 24px;
      background: #aaa;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity .2s ease;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
    .main button:hover {
      opacity: .9;
    }
    .main button:active {
      box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    /* main color */
    .a-green big,
    .a-green h3 {
      color: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-green h4 {
      color: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-green button {
      background: #4c7737;
    }
    .a-yel big,
    .a-yel h3 {
      color: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-yel h4 {
      color: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-yel button {
      background: #ffbb42;
    }
    .a-red big,
    .a-red h3 {
      color: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-red h4 {
      color: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-red button {
      background: #e13c4c;
    }
    .a-blue big,
    .a-blue h3 {
      color: #2e5dea;
    }
    .a-blue h4 {
      color: #2e5dea;
    }
    .a-blue button {
      background: #2e5dea;
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row white">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <ul class="main a-green">
            <li>
              <big>COLLAPSIBLE 1</big>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4>Acordions</h4>
            </li>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <ul class="main a-yel">
            <li>
              <big>COLLAPSIBLE 2</big>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4>Acordions</h4>
            </li>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse4">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse5">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse6">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <ul class="main a-blue">
            <li>
              <big>COLLAPSIBLE 3</big>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4>Acordions</h4>
            </li>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse7">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse8">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse9">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <ul class="main a-red">
              <li>
                <big>COLLAPSIBLE 4</big>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>Acordions</h4>
              </li>
              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse10">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse11">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse12">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse12" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
        <!-- /block -->
    </div>
      <!-- /row -->
  </section>
```